# White Noise Process

Tags: time-series

[image]

Assuming that $a_t$ is a White Noise process with 0 mean and $\sigma^2$ as variance

I know how to prove $E(Z_t)$ = 0 but does anyone know how to prove the variance and covariance parts (for $k\neq0$)? Thanks a lot

Comment: Please type math equations in MathJax.

Comment: @whuber Actually, the OP does tell us that he is assuming that $\{a_t\}$ is white noise with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The variance is straightforward. Start with
$$
\mathrm{Var}(Z_t)= \mathrm{Var}\left(\frac{a_t}{\phi^2} \right)
+  \left(1-\frac{1}{\phi^2}\right)^2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathrm{Var}\left(\frac{a_{t+k}}{\phi^k} \right)
$$
and evaluate the (geometric) sum.

The covariance is a little fiddlier. For $s>0$ you have
$$
\mathrm{Cov}(Z_t, Z_{t+s}) = \mathrm{Cov}\left( \frac{a_t}{\phi^2} 
-  \left(1-\frac{1}{\phi^2}\right) \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_{t+k}}{\phi^k},
\frac{a_{t+s}}{\phi^2} 
-  \left(1-\frac{1}{\phi^2}\right) \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_{t+s+k}}{\phi^k}
\right)
$$
and you need to work out which terms contribute to the correlation. For example, $a_t$ does not appear in $Z_{t+s}$, so you can ignore it.

Similarly, $Z_t$ contains the terms $a_{t+k}, a_{t+k+1}, \ldots, a_{t+s-1}$ which can also be ignored.